# Installing Magento Extensions on a Custom Theme

Tags: magento

I'm building a Magento theme, and the extensions that I've installed so far do not work well with my website. As it seems, some of the plugins are not showing any display on the front-end (others show, but not completely as intended).

In general practice, when building a custom theme and installing extensions, are the extensions installed in the custom theme's directories or in the base or default directories? I haven't yet ruled out the possibility that Magento is unable to find all the proper files because it's looking in the wrong place, and that while it should be looking in the theme files, the files are not there, because they're installed in the base path instead.

I saw something on those lines over here: http://www.collaboration133.com/magento-extensions-not-displaying-on-frontend-after-install/2693/

What's the common standard (as far as directories) for successfully installing a Magento extension? Also, if I need to reinstall it in the custom theme directory, is there a simple way to do this, or must this be done manually? Thanks!

Comment: As long as your custom theme doesn't remove any blocks from the layouts those themes should just work. You can copy them into your own theme, put them in the default or base -- if your theme extends default and default extends base the files will be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Magento folder structure is concerned, it checks the files in:

1. `<current theme package>  -->  <current theme folder>`
2. `<current theme package>  -->  <default folder in current theme's package>`
3. `base  -->  default folder`

So if the extension has files in suppose `default --> defaul`t folder and your theme package already has a default folder, then extension files will not be accessible by default.

You need to manually copy those files into your theme.

Comment: I moved the files and the extension started working. Thank you!